# How can I detect whether a mouse click is long or short?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

I need to detect if an user holds the mouse down for a long time on a button or quickly clicks it.

Here is my test code. The mTimer value is set in onMouseDown() but it evaluates to false in mTimeout(). What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [mouseInfo, setMouseInfo] = useState({
    mTimer: null,
    action: ""
  });

  const mTimeout = () => {
    if (mouseInfo && mouseInfo.mTimer) {
      setMouseInfo({
        mTimer: null,
        action: "More than 1 sec passed"
      });
    }
  };

  const onMouseDown = (ev) => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(mTimeout, 1000);
    console.log(typeof timeoutId, Boolean(timeoutId));
    setMouseInfo({
      mTimer: timeoutId,
      action: "mousedown"
    });
  };

  const onMouseUp = (ev) => {
    if (mouseInfo.mTimer) {
      clearTimeout(mouseInfo.mTimer);
      setMouseInfo({
        mTimer: null,
        action: "Mouseup before 1 sec"
      });
    } else {
      setMouseInfo({
        mTimer: null,
        action: "Mouseup after 1 sec"
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onMouseDown={onMouseDown} onMouseUp={onMouseUp}>
        Click my slowly
      </button>
      <p>{mouseInfo.action}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can try this on:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mouseup-mousedown-timeout-test-78qc1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The problem is that mTimeout() doesn't see the updated state, only an old one. You can fix this example by not rely upon the state in the timeout method, but how can you access the correct state if you should need it inside the timeout method?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

This is not working because `setMouseInfo` doesn't change state immediately.

```js
const onMouseDown = (ev) => {
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(mTimeout, 1000);
  console.log(typeof timeoutId, Boolean(timeoutId));
  setMouseInfo({
    mTimer: timeoutId,
    action: "mousedown"
  });
};
```

So `mouseInfo.mTimer` would not be set even after one second, thus it might be `null`.

```js
const mTimeout = () => {
  console.log("mTimeout");
  if (mouseInfo && mouseInfo.mTimer) {
    setMouseInfo({
      mTimer: null,
      action: "More than 1 sec passed"
    });
  } 
};
```

#### Solution

Just remove or comment if statement which check `mouseInfo` and `mouseInfo.mTimer`.

```js
const mTimeout = () => {
  console.log("mTimeout");
  // if (mouseInfo && mouseInfo.mTimer) {
   setMouseInfo({
    mTimer: null,
    action: "More than 1 sec passed"
    })
  // }
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mouseup-mousedown-timeout-test-forked-jw44r?file=/src/App.js

Comment: "This is not working because setMouseInfo doesn't change state immediately." - well the text on the page below the button changes to "mousedown" almost immediately which means the state changes long before that 1 sec timeout. The problem is that mTimeout() doesn't see the updated state, only an old one. Yes you can fix this example by not rely upon the state in the timeout method, but how can you access the correct state if you should need it inside the timeout method?